# Proof of $L_N\geq c\log N$

Tags: fourier-series

> Let $D_N$ denote the Dirichlet kernel
>   $$D_N(\theta)=\sum_{n=-N}^Ne^{ik\theta}=\frac{\sin((N+\frac 1 2) \theta)}{\sin (\frac {\theta} 2)}$$ 
>   And define $$L_N=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|D_N(\theta)|d\theta$$
>   Prove that $L_N\geq c\log N$

Could you help me understand these 4 steps that I remarked below, they literally do not ring any bell to me..

Since $\frac x {\sin x}\geq 1 $ for $x\in [-\frac {\pi}2,\frac {\pi}2]$, it follows that
$$|D_N(\theta)|\geq 2\frac {|{\sin((N+\frac 1 2) \theta})|}{\theta}$$ 
Then, $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|D_N(\theta)|d\theta \\ \geq 4\int_0^{\pi}\frac {|{\sin((N+\frac 1 2) \theta})|}{\theta} d\theta $$ $$=4\int_0^{(N+\frac 1 2)\pi}\frac {|{\sin \theta}|}{\theta} d\theta  \\  
\geq  4\int_0^{N\pi}\frac {|{\sin \theta}|}{\theta} d\theta$$ 
$$=4\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac {|{\sin \theta}|}{\theta} d\theta $$
$$\geq 4\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac 1 {(k+1)\pi}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}{|{\sin \theta}|} d\theta \tag 1$$
$$=\frac 8 {\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac 1 {(k+1)} \tag 2$$
$$=\frac 8 {\pi}\log(N+1) \tag 3\\ \geq \frac 8 {\pi}\log N \\ \therefore L_N\geq c\log N$$

Comment: If none of these 5 steps make sense for you, fourier analysis might be too complicated as of now

Comment: One was a change of variable that I realised later.. But others still need to be clarified @mathworker21

Comment: (1) is just splitting up the integral

Comment: Oh, yes ! I am updating the post then..

Comment: (1) is just saying $\theta \le (k+1)\pi$ in the range of integration $[k\pi, (k+1)\pi]$.

Comment: Since answers are referring to your numberings, it might be more useful to keep them fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @mathworker21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) $\frac{|\sin\theta|}{\theta} \geq \frac{|\sin\theta|}{(k+1)\pi}$ for $\theta\in [k\pi,\ (k+1)\pi]$.

(2) Calculate the integral of sine, which is either always positive or negative depending on $k$. (which is 2).

(3) I am not sure about equality, but you can use $\sum_1^{N}\frac{1}{k} \geq \int_1^{N+1} 1/k = \log(N+1)$

Comment: You should be sure that equality does not hold (for all N). One is irrational, one is rational.